# I want to clear one item in listbox winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, indexing

I want to clear one item in a listbox winforms c#.

How can I get the index of the item?

Comment: You use the remove method on the listbox.

Answer (score 3):

`ListBox` has a property called `SelectedIndex`. To remove current selected item you have just to call `RemoveAt(int)` method.

Example:

```
int selectedIndex = myListBox.SelectedIndex;
if(selectedIndex >=0)
   myListBox.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
```